# Unable to change exposure settings for CSI Pi Camera on Raspberry Pi 64 bit Bullseye

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi4, picamera

Tried varying the expsoure settings for the Pi CSI based camera using libcamera library in python.
Tried out multiple methods which did not lead to successful implementation.

Unable to vary exposure using the following example code:

```
        cam.set(libcamera.AeEnable, 0)
        cam.set(libcamera.ExposureValue, 4)
        cam.set(libcamera.ExposureTime, 100000)
        cam.set(libcamera.AnalogueGain, -0.1)
```

Experienced no change in exposure when varying the above settings over libcamera.

But I was successful in varying the brightness using the following command:

```
cam.set(libcamera.Brightness, -1)
```

---

I also tried  using the PiCamera library and experienced the following error:

`OSError: libmmal.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Found that the community has already faced similar problems.
The posts shared that the above library is not present in 64 bit os.

---

I also tried `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2` inorder to have the CSI camera detected as a device allowing it to be accessed using OpenCV since several blog posts shared this procedure as a possibility.

The camera was not picked up over OpenCV and returned nothing.
[Blog](https://hub.packtpub.com/using-raspberry-pi-camera-module/)
[Hackster Blog](https://www.hackster.io/mjrobot/real-time-face-recognition-an-end-to-end-project-a10826)

Comment: If you're using Bullseye. Why not try PiCamera2?